# How to enter integer value into input box

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have below HTML tags, i want to pass/sendkeys to input box.

```
<input type="number" value="null" step="1" min="0" max="2" class="abc">
```

'sendkeys' is not working since above input 'type' is "number".(with sendkeys it's accepting only "string" values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the `SendKeys()` would do it. So far I know you can send whatever you want as string and the page should manipulate it as `int`. However, if that's not the case you can use `JavaScriptExecutor` to set the value of attribute `value`

```
    string value = "1234";
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver).ExecuteScript(
        "document.querySelector(\"[type='number'][step='1']\").setAttribute('value','" + value + "');");
```

Note: the code above is C# code and inside the `querySelector` you can use any valid `cssSelector`

Comment: Saifur has a great suggestion. Inside of an input text box, the server is going to initially parse it as a string anyway. Even if it is a string, is SendKeys trying to put in a quoted value into the box, or can you put in digits unquoted. You could just let the server cast the string to an int anyway.